# As I can send information only by Ethernet interface in multicasocket

Tags: java, sockets

I have two network interfaces(Wireless and Ethernet) for connection but I just want to send information to  Ethernet, when i don't have conecction in ethernet the multicast-socket  can send the information by Wireless but i don't want

Comment: However, note that the accepted answer to that question is wrong.  You can bind a socket to a network address, so if you know the local IP of the wired connection you can bind to that.

Comment: Exactly. Bind the socket to the IP address of the Ethernet NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your socket to the specific IP address of the adapter you want to use, using the `Socket#bind(SocketAddress endpoint)` method.

The `java.net.NetworkInterface` class can be used to enumerate the available interfaces and get their IP addresses.